# How do you copy output from the emacs debugger?

Tags: debugging, emacs

When you toggle debug-on-error and trigger an error, the debugging output is shown in a buffer.

How do you copy this text for future use?

When I try to navigate in the buffer to select a region, emacs becomes unresponsive. (Perhaps it is debugging the action of selecting text?)

When I press 'q' to quit the debugger, the buffer is lost.

Emacs 26.3
Fedora 30  x86_64

Comment: It's not normal for Emacs to be unresponsive in the `*Backtrace*` buffer.  Usually you could switch to it and `C-x h M-w` to copy everything in the usual way.  If you run `emacs -Q` do you see the same thing?  If so, what about using `toggle-debug-on-quit` and then `M-x C-g` ?

Comment: It works for me with Emacs 26.2 on Linux. What Emacs and what OS do you use?

Comment: What @phils said - try `emacs -Q`. If no problem with that then bisect your init file to find the culprit.